# Django-Why doesn't the likes system work?

Tags: django

Why is the likes system not working? Аfter clicking on the "like" button I get an error.

```
class ImageDetail(DetailView):
    model=Image
    template_name='images/image/detail.html'
    context_object_name='image'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Image.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id'),slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        likes_connected=get_object_or_404(Image, id=self.kwargs['id'],slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        liked=False
        if likes_connected.users_like.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked=True
        data['number_of_likes']=likes_connected.number_of_likes()
        data['post_is_liked']=liked
        return data

    
def ImagePostLike(request,id,slug):
    image=get_object_or_404(Image, id=request.POST.get('image_id'), slug=request.POST.get('image_slug'))
    if image.users_like.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        image.users_like.remove(request.user)
    else:
        image.users_like.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('image_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug]))
```

Why is the likes system not working? Аfter clicking on the "like" button I get an error.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
app_name = 'images'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.image_create, name='create'),
    path('detail/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.ImageDetail.as_view(), name='image_detail'),
    path('image_like/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.ImagePostLike, name='image_like'),

]
```

Why is the likes system not working? Аfter clicking on the "like" button I get an error.
detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% block title %}{{image.title}}{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ image.title }}</h1>
<img src="{{ image.url }}" class="image-detail">

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="{% url 'images:image_like' image.id image.slug%}">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if post_is_liked %}

<button type="submit" name="image_id" value="{{image.id}}" class="btn btn-info">Unlike</button>

{% else %}
<button type="submit" name="image_id" value="{{image.id}}" class="btn btn-info">Like</button>
{% endif %}
</form>
{% else %}
 <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">>Log in to like this article!</a><br>
{% endif %}
<strong class="text-secondary">{{ number_of_likes }}  Like</strong>
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='images_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url=models.URLField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,
                               db_index=True)
    users_like=models.ManyToManyField(User,
    related_name='image_like')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('images:detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.users_like.count()
```

As I understand it, the problem lies in the slug.

Comment: Hi! Can you share the error? Hard to guess what's going on without it

Comment: https://postimg.cc/5QptvpQW